# Sub-Folder style routing in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to parse simple routes like these:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/
```

where there is no theoretical limitation to the number of them. And it would be nice to have an array `['foo','bar','baz']` from it.

How to do it with Express routing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression.

```
app.get(/^\/((?:[^\/]+\/?)+)\//, function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.params[0].split('/'));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Run it and then

```
$ curl localhost:8080/foo/bar/baz/
["foo","bar","baz"]
```