# Passing unknown number of params to NodeJS routes

Tags: node.js, express

How can I pass an unknown number of params to NodeJS routes, and save them to an array?:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/param1/param2/param3...
```

I thought about doing:

```
app.get('/*', myHandler);
```

And just tokenize the string, but there should be a better way.

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114805/sub-folder-style-routing-in-express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using express routing in NodeJS.  If so, you might want to experiment with the regular expressions.   Like the following will give you the full path (/vararg/) in req.params[0] but there may be a better way:

```
app.get(/^\/vararg\/(.*)/, function(req,res) {  
    res.send("Got parameters : " + req.params[0]); 
})
```

So if I do a get on localhost:3000/vararg/foo/bar/gar it will send:

> Got parameters : foo/bar/gar

Or localhost:3000/vararg/foo will produce:

> Got parameters : foo

And then you can split the parameter into the other parts.