# node.js - how to work with flexible numbers of parameters?

Tags: node.js, express

Take a look in this call:

```
//http://myserver.com/products/list/categories/
//http://myserver.com/products/list/categories/shoes/
//http://myserver.com/products/list/categories/shoes/woman
//http://myserver.com/products/list/categories/shoes/woman/leather
```

It's like a webshop where you will have a root category and undefined number of categories

So, on my node.js code, I'd like to implement a sort of flexible number of categories and I don't know how to work in this way. Never did it before.

I've the sentence bellow, but this will allow me to work with a single argument.

```
app.get('/arg1:/products/list/categories/:argument', productsCategories.index);
```

I can do such things like place a very good amount of parameters such as:

```
app.get('/arg1:/products/list/categories/:par1:', productsCategories.index);
app.get('/arg1:/products/list/categories/:par1:/par2', productsCategories.index);
app.get('/arg1:/products/list/categories/:par1:/par2:/par3', productsCategories.index);
//...par4, par5,par6......par20
```

and mat to the same file and test the parameters. but I don't this that's the best way. Any clue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sub-Folder style routing in Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114805/sub-folder-style-routing-in-express)

Comment: Not exactly...this example is very dynamic since the beginning. The /product/list/categories must be hard-coded. but I believe to be possible to fit that example to my needs in some how.

Comment: look here then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017071/passing-unknown-number-of-params-to-nodejs-routes

Comment: this is not a Node.js related question, it's express! and this can be done using regular expressions

Comment: Is this correct ? I really hate regEx...
app.get('/:webshopId/products/list/categories/:argument', productsCategories.index);
will be app.get('/:webshopId/products/list/categories/(.*)/', productsCategories.index);

Comment: there is no other way, if you don't want to create yourself a string parser which would get the parameters you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use a regex to capture the routes and then split them.

```
app.get(/^\/(.+?)\/products\/list\/categories\/((?:[^\/]+\/?)+)/, function(req, res) {
  // /test/products/list/categories/shoes/woman/leather would return [['test'],['shoes','woman','leather']]
  var webShopId = req.params[0];
  var categories = req.params[1].split('/');
});
```

Comment: Can I do in this way ?
app.get(/\/arg1:\/products\/list\/categories\/((?:[^\/]+\/?)+)/, function(req, res) {
  var categories = req.params[0].split('/');
});
I mean..there is a parameter before the product...

Comment: Then just add an extra capture group at the beginning and change the array index for `req.params`.

Comment: Almost there, Ben ;) Just help me to fix this, plz...
Your example looks awesome...but when I try to put an initial parameter before the static ones...something went wrong..take a look...
app.get(/\/:arg1\/products\/list\/categories\/((?:[^\/]+\/?)+)/, productsCategories.index);