# Get specific parameter no matter the URL in Express.JS

Tags: node.js, express

I want to check for a consistent URL parameter in each request in my Express.JS app. The base of the URL is always the same:

`/command/UUID`

But some times it can be

`/command/UUID/something/1`

The following code works only in the first case. As soon as I add another slash at the end, this middleware won't be executed.

```
app.all('/*/:uuid', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.params)

    next();

});
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me out solve this issue.

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually worked is the following code

```
app.set('strict routing', false );
app.all('/:cmd/:uuid*', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.params)

    next();

});
```

And the result is as follow with this URL: `/ip/165420/3123123/adasdsad`

`{ '0': '/3123123/adasdsad', cmd: 'ip', uuid: '165420' }`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
app.all('/:command/:uuid/(*?)', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.params.command, req.params.uuid);

    next();

});
```

Comment: Almost: it doesn't work if there is no `/` at the end.

Comment: Can you verify if you have enabled `strict routing`? It is disabled by default in Express though. `app.set('strict routing', false);`

Comment: It is set to false. And I can query the same URL with or without `/`.

Comment: @DavidGatti See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114805/sub-folder-style-routing-in-express

Comment: that is not the solution that I'm looking for, I could also use the URL class from NodeJS, even better then splitting. But I would rather not do that. I would use what ExpressJS has to offer if possible.